# Find process and print application name in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have Raw PS command output in a file and i want find like if pmon is found then i need to print like Oracle,Database, if the Jboss found need to print like Jboss,Middle-ware.

I have the mapping file like below

Pmon,Oracle,Database
Jboss,Jboss,Middle-ware
Weblogic,Weblogic,Middle-ware.

i need to write a shell script for this, can you please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOmething like this, maybe?:

```
$ cat foo
pmon Oracle,Database
jboss Jboss,Middle-ware
weblogic Weblogic,Middle-ware. 
bash Bash,shell
```

Code:

```
$ ps | awk '
BEGIN {                           # hash the mapping file foo in the BEGINning:
    while((getline < "foo") > 0)  # read records from file
        a[$1]=$2                  # hash to a
    close("foo") }                # be nice now and shut it up
$NF in a { $0=$0 OFS a[$NF] }     # append mapping to the end of output
1'                                # print
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4611 pts/3    00:00:04 bash Bash,shell
15691 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
15692 pts/3    00:00:00 awk
31785 pts/3    00:00:00 emacs
```

Downside: `a[$1]=$2` only allows one word mappings, mapping like:

```
emacs greatest entity's right hand
```

would fail (well, not entirely, it would output `emacs greatest` :).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jamesh for your time.

I am able to achieve with this
while read line
do
txtgrep=`echo $line | cut -d@ -f1`
txtappend=`echo $line | cut -d@ -f2`
done

i have modified the mapping file like
jboss@jboss,middleware